# Canonical web page layout articles

Tags: layout, e-commerce, wireframe

I need scientific works or articles  about canonical layout forms used in e-commerce shops, something about prototyping and trying them on a real audience. 
Maybe can you lead me were I can found something like this information, or maybe you now that about the new names for this structure?

I found this example but it's old one:
[image: Canonical forms example (old)]

I doing a research work on this but I can't find any information, so I hope somebody will lead me the right way!

Thant you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "canonical"?

Comment: @moot  It's a type of the web design layout

Comment: Yeah it's not a type of web design. Canonical is a rarely used old word about an observation about old design. The example you gave is from a rare old book. If you google it you'll see how few results there are. Material Design has great new, proven, tested, style guidelines and nomenclature.

Comment: @moot Thank you! I need any lead about that canonical design even if it's old because, I'm writing a paper for my bachelor's degree and they gave me this theme. So now I know that l'll write about that now we don't use it and why. If you know any more information about it please share.

Comment: Modern usage of the word "Canonical" is an attempt to convey significance of convention, usually a specific convention, in a manner beyond any reproach or criticism, query or analysis. It always fails when used in computing and its various offshoots because there's nothing approaching canonical within the entire field. It is the least appropriate attempt at metaphorical reinforcement of belief in a field full of flunks, flukes, foibles, fallacies and fictions.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many best practices for e-commerce UX and most of them are regularly updated over the years.

I recommend you look into [Baymard Institute](https://baymard.com/blog), they do UX research focused on e-commerce and have tons of great articles going into the details of their studies and recommendations.

If you need a quick layout recommendation, they also benchmark the largest [e-commerce sites page by page](https://baymard.com/ux-benchmark). You cannot see the details for the public access, but it does indicate what interface approach breaks a guideline. And if you refer back to their articles, you can often pinpoint what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it being an assignment explains why that word Canonical.

Look to NNGroup. If there's anything of value that's Canonical, it's in NNGroup. NNGroup is the main old UX company. They're all about articles on UX design and testing. You'll find lots of old articles on design.

[This is probably the first set of UI design rules created by the leader of NNGroup in 95.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

[Here's an actual article on Canonical Intranet Homepages by NNGroup.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-canonical-intranet-homepage/) Note it's inTRAnet but it looks like that doesn't matter.